# Context Menu not appearing in TableView Cell with button

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu

I have implemented a context menu in UITableViewCell using the table view cell delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview?
```

Inside my table view cell, there's a button. Normallya long press on the cell should trigger the appearance of a context menu. However, if the user performs a long press on the button or the button's container, the context menu does not appear, and the button's action is triggered instead.

To resolve this, I disabled the button and added a tap gesture. This modification allowed the context menu to appear upon a long press, and the regular tap/click gesture worked as expected.

I'm a bit curious why the table view doesn't automatically handle this situation & whether there's a more elegant solution to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the 'User Interaction Enabled' on both button and button's container in Interface Builder. and then it should show your context menu.

Below is example code that you must implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let provider: UIContextMenuActionProvider = { _ in
            UIMenu(title: "Title", children: [
                UIAction(title: "Copy") { _ in
                    // do copy
                },
                UIAction(title: "Cut") { _ in
                    // do cut
                }
            ])
        }
        
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: provider)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I've already explored disabling User Interaction & mentioned in the description. My specific requirement is to find a better solution while keeping the button in the enabled state.